# Compare current time to time user sets in dateTimePicker

Tags: c#

```cs
public bool CheckTime()
{
    if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay == dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also tried `.TotalSeconds`

```cs
public bool CheckTime()
{
    if (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `dateTimePickers` format is set to `Time`.

How can I compare the time set in the `datetimepicker` and the current system time?

Comment: what is output?

Comment: Note that `TotalSeconds` is a `double`; it includes fractions of a second. If you want to compare to the second, you should cast it to `int`. Try `(int)DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == (int)dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds`.

Comment: To what end? What will you do if it is? *What do you want your program to do?*

Answer (score 0):

```
(int)DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds == (int)dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay.TotalSeconds
```

Now it's working, THANK YOU <3

Comment: Also, you can literally just put `return` in front of that; no need for the `if...else` block.